# Google Maps API v3 *broken* in Safari 6.0.2

Tags: google-maps

I have a fairly straightforward Google Maps implementation running well in Chrome on a Mac. Yet - I am not working on the mobile implementation as well as cross-browser fixes, and have discovered that the map itself is not properly displaying / functioning, let alone the markers and infowindows that should be showing up. The native zoom tool never displays and I can't click anywhere on the map or drag it.

I've been googling and googling but not turning much up. Any hints or help would be much appreciated (while realizing this is not specifically a code question - yet).

I discovered the prob on my own app, but tested using Google's 'hello world' for the maps API, and it's exactly the same issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
  <head>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />  
    <style type="text/css">  
      html { height: 100% }  
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }  
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }  
    </style>  
    <script type="text/javascript"  
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDSh0tsHL1DQBwI0-xfuQkUezonGxlt39k&sensor=false">  
    </script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      function initialize() {  
        var mapOptions = {  
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),  
          zoom: 8,  
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
        };  
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);  
    </script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
    <div id="map-canvas"/>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a css problem, but you really haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: Just appended my post with some code - thanks!

Comment: what sets the width of the map div?

Comment: wow - that did it. i am *sure* i had tried adding in the width - but i restarted safari this time and that seemed to do it (cached?). thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your map doesn't have a completely defined size.  You need to specify both the height and width, either as percent up to a parent element that has a size or specifically define the size of the div.  If the size isn't defined it is zero.